# how to use camera position and rotation by copy another one in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I want to switch two `cameraControls` (`orbitControl` and `pointLockControl`).  I create two camera, switch `cameraControls` by change camera in `renderer()` function. When camera change set current `cameraposition` and rotation by copy the last camera position and rotation. But the current camera rotation will be odd, the rotation on x axis looks like not based on camera self coordinate system.

```
intermediateCamera = MKY.Camera.current;
keyControlCamera.position.copy(intermediateCamera.position);
keyControlCamera.rotation.copy(intermediateCamera.rotation);
orbitControl.enabled = false;
keyControl.enabled = true;
MKY.Camera.current = keyControlCamera;
```

How to use last camera position and rotation to current camera?

Comment: Try copying the `up` and `quaternion` properties as well.

Comment: @TheJim01   I have try ,but It looks like not work very well.It looks like camera rotation based on world coordinate system.I do not understand what is difference between change camera.rotation and camera.quaternion.